# c# filter a collection by LIKE

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am using c# and Visual Studio 2017.

The program recieves thousands of messages a minute.

A message is made up of OID field(s). OIDs are a series of digits seprared by a period. Each OID is linked to a single value.

```
Three Example Message
    OID=1.2.3.4.5.6           Value=Hello
    OID=1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9     Value=Hello1
    OID=1.2.3.4.5.6.1         Value=Hello2
```

Each time a message is recieved it's OID is extracted to a String variable.

There exists say no more than 30 OIDs separated by a comma in App.config.

```
App.config
<!-- "The list of OIDs in messages to redact their values."-->
<add key="RedactOids" value="1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9,1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.6.2.39.0" />
```

I need to load the OID config values (as strings) set in App.config into some sort of set/list/collection/dictonary/array/other - what's the best structure as lookup speed is important?

When a message is recieved a OID lookup (something similar to String.startsWith('%1.2.3%')) should be carried out against those OIDs loaded in to set/list/collection/dictonary/array/other.

```
Example:
    App.config OIDs = 1.2.3.4

Message OID
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8     matched on first 4 digits to the OID in the config
1.3.4.5.6              not matched
1.2.3.4.0             matched on first 4 digits to the OID in the config
2.3.4.1.2.3.4       not matched, NB: 1.2.3.4 not the first four digits
```

What's the best way to store the OIDs from App.config so a start-of-string pattern match can be performed?

Regards

Comment: _"what's the best structure as lookup speed is important?"_ That partly depends on the distribution of values. If I were you, I'd come up with 3 or 4 different (simple) approaches and benchmark them. If neither of them meets your speed requirements, I'd go on to add the next more complex solution and benchmark again.

Comment: Your question does not seem consistent. "assume that the OID value in the message will only pattern match on one of the OIDs loaded from the App.config". In the example given there seem to be multiple possible matches. And the logic seem to be `Contains` rather than `StartsWith`.

Comment: I have re-worded the example, hopefully this is clearer

Comment: If there are no more than 30 OIDs, there's a good chance that keeping them in a list and doing something like a simple `oids.Where(oid => message.OidPrefix.StartsWith(oid))` won't produce any noticeable lag. I would start with that, and unless it produces measurable slowness in your app, don't worry about hyper-optimizing the data structure.

Comment: (Use a `StringComparison.Ordinal` argument for a small, but easy, gain in performance)

Comment: @ StriplingWarrior - thanks for geeting back. Are you able to go in to more detail around the code as c# is not my area. I was looking at the "List" in c# but could not find any 'Where' - where is 'Where' coming from ? (that is a tongue twister!)

OK - i have found this...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0